# Efficiently creating pairs of random array items in PHP that meet certain criteria

Tags: php

I have three arrays:

`$a` with five elements, and `$b` & `c` with four elements.

Each member of `$a` has to be paired randomly exactly three times with a member from `$b` or `$c`. However, each element from `$b` and `$c` has to be paired randomly with exactly *five* elements from the other two arrays.

Each of these pairings must be unique, and an element can't be paired with itself.

Eg:

```
$a = array('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5');
$b = array('b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4');
$c = array('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4');
```

The pairings for `a1` could look like:

```
'a1', 'b3'
'a1', 'b4'
'a1', 'c2'
```

And the pairings for `c3` could look like

```
'c3', 'a2'
'c3', 'b3'
'c3', 'a4'
```

So again, I'm trying to make random pairings that:

1. An element must be matched to elements from the other arrays (and so they can't match themselves). They can be in any number from either one.
2. Each matching must be unique
3. Elements in `$a` must be matched exactly 3 times, elements in `$b` or `$c` must be matched exactly five times, EXCEPT (edit!) one element from `$c` which can only be matched four times.

I found a solution that works by essentially shuffling the arrays and checking to see if they line up, but obviously this is very slow -- it takes about 100-5000 attempts to get one that works. Since this is for a simulation which will occur thousands/millions of times, this is not going to cut it. I'm hoping there's an approach that could generate these pairings on the first try.

Comment: Is this a homework? I don't get what other use it could have.

Comment: Imagine you've got a matching for all but the last choice. Consider how your potential choices for that last one are limited by the rules you've stated. Now work backwards, looking at which options are available for each state, assuming the previous states have already been filled. Hint: "must be matched exactly *n* times" is a pretty restrictive rule straight away.

Comment: OK, maybe I'm crazy, but I have to ask - as I understand the rules as you've laid them out, there are 0 possible valid results. To illustrate this more clearly, A requires 15 occurrences (5 members with 3 a piece) of its members be made to satisfy its rules, B needs 20 (4 members with 5 showings each) to satisfy its rules, and C needs another 20 to satisfy its rules. But this is impossible, as the rules are stated, because a match requires 2 **and only 2** occurrences! I've tried it on paper, and order/randomness doesn't matter - there is always one left over, unmatched, breaking the rules.

Comment: So that's 55 occurrences, and 2 is not a factor of 55. Have I misunderstood your rules - does both A and B and C require "exactly n" matches, with no leftovers and not a single over/under use?

Comment: You're very right. I omitted that one of the elements from $c should only be matched 4x and not 5x, which I mistakenly thought was a trivial change. Sorry! And MightyPork -- I'm simulating NFL seasons and this was the format from 1970-1976.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using some advice from Dave, I figured it out. I'm sure there's an easier way to do it, but here's the gist of what I did:

**Prepwork -- Create an array where `$b` can be matched to `$c`**

1. Make an array that contains each member of `$b` five times.
2. Shuffle that array, and cut it after the 8th member. The first part goes into one array, we'll call it `$a_choices`. With the second part, which we'll call `$b_choices`, call `array_count_values()` and determine how many times each element appears.
3. Make an array that contains each member of `$c` five times (except one which will appear 4x), we'll call it `$c_list`. Then using the histogram above, make an array from elements of `$c` based on how many times a member appears. Eg, if members from `$b` appeared 3x, 3x, 4x, and 2x, then I need four elements from `$c`: two that appear 4x, one that's 3x, and one that's 1x. These are put into an array, `$c_choices`. The elements are picked randomly from `$c_list`, and moved from that array and put into `$c_choices`.
4. Call `array_merge($a_choices, $c_list)` to merge what's leftover. Now there are 15 elements for `$a` to grab from, and there are 12 leftover for both `$c` and `$b`.

**Select matches for `$a` first**

1. Go through each element in `$a`, and make three random choices from `$a_choices`. HOWEVER, if any element appears too often, it needs to be grabbed this time. Eg, if I'm matching the second-to-last element in `$a`, then I need to grab any element from `$a_choices` that appears twice. If I'm selecting the third-to-last, then I grab any elements that appear 3x. Etc. This makes sure that the last element from `$a` can make 3 unique matches.

**Match `$b`**

1. Now using the elements in `$b`, match them to elements from `$c_choices` in the same way we did for elements from `$a` -- again making sure to always select any elements that appear too often. The whole point of the prepwork part is to make sure that there is exactly the right combination of elements from `$b` and `$c` leftover to make it match every time.